# When will this quadratic be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics

What are all the positive integer solutions to the equation $m^2 + m - 1$, such that the output is a square number? I can tell that $m-1$ must be the negative or positive sum of odd numbers, so $m-1$ must be in the form $2mk + k^2$ where k is any integer. So we are left with $2m(k-1) + k^2 + 1 =0$, in which k can be any integer and m must be positive integer, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this unfortunately. Any help? Might it be useful that $|m-1|$ must be the difference of two squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$m^2 < m^2 + m - 1 < m^2 + 2m + 1 = (m +  1)^2$$
for $m \ne 1$. This means that for $m \ne 1$ the number $m^2 + m - 1$ lies strictly between two consecutive squares and therefore cannot be a square itself.

Comment: ok, i guess i was being stupid. But there is another special case then where $m-1=0$